# is it possible to build ATL project in VS express 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, atl

i know that ATL and MFC are now part of Windows Driver Kit 
my question is how can i (if it possible .. ) to build project or import ATL project 
to visual studio express

Answer (score 0):

Check if your ATL project is within the scope defined in [the DDK release note](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/wdk/RelNotesW7.mspx#EXLAE).